# Google API Chart with PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i'm trying to use Google Live charts API to display a single Line chart that only show a Numeric value in the Y axis and date value in X axis.

> MYSQL: 
>   Estado: Numeric
>   Hora: date

This is my code, i dunno very much of php so i tried a example that i found but i cant make it work.

```
<?php

 $public =  "admin"; //This is the user i search in the LIKE





class conect

{

private $host;

private $root;

private $pass;

private $db;



public function dbconect($host,$root,$pass,$db)

{

$this->host = $host;

$this->root = $root;

$this->pass = $pass;

$this->db   = $db;

$this->conexion = mysql_connect($this->host,$this->root,$this->pass);

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

mysql_select_db( $this->db, $this->conexion );

}



//se cierra la conexión

public function dbcerrar()

{

mysql_close($this->conexion);

}

//

}



$conex=new conect();



 $conex->dbconect("localhost","root","","database");

//extraccion array de datos

$res = mysql_query("SELECT Estado AS total,Hora FROM Datos WHERE Usuario LIKE '$public'");

while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($res))

{

$arrayhombres[$arr['Hora']] = array(

'Hora' => $arr['Hora'],

'total' => $arr['total'],

);

}





/*

echo "<pre>";

print_r($arrayhombres);

echo "</pre>";

*/

?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});  

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);



 function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

          ['Fecha', 'Bateria', 'Mujeres','Sin datos'],



          ['<?php echo date("Y-m-d", $i);?>',<?php echo $totalhombres;?>,<?php echo $totalsindatos;?>],

 <?php 

 }

 ?>

        ]);



        var options = {

          title: 'Estadistica Registros',

 pointShape: 'circle',

 pointSize: 3,//tamaño de los puntos

 series: {//colores de las lineas

            0: { color: '#29ab1e' },

            1: { color: '#2f7ce4' },

          },

 titleTextStyle: {color: '#db6c00',fontSize: 14},//estilos

 tooltip: { textStyle: { color: '#3d3d3d', fontSize: 10 }},//estilo toltip

 legend: {textStyle: {color: '#535353', fontSize: 12 }},//estilos leyenda

 vAxis: { textStyle: {color: '#3d3d3d', fontSize: 12 }},//estilos horizontal

 hAxis: { textStyle: {color: '#3d3d3d', fontSize: 12 }}//estilos vertical

        };



        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);

      }

</script>

<div id="chart_div" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Comment: The variable $public is the one up that is equals to "admin"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple issues, if this is your full code.

You start out by querying your database for all of the rows of a certain user (for example, 'admin'). Then you take those values and put them into an array `$arrayhombres` keyed on the hours/horas that you don't use again. Instead you can query your database and directly add the rows to your graph.

```
...
$res = mysql_query("SELECT Estado AS total,Hora FROM Datos WHERE Usuario LIKE '$public'");
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});  
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Fecha/Date', 'Total Hombres'],
      <?php
        while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
          echo '[Date('.$arr['Hora'].'),'.$arr['total'].'],';
        }
      ?>
    ]
 ...
```

**It is important to know what kind of format your 'Fecha/Hora' column is.** You will likely have to convert the dates from what you have stored in your SQL database into a javascript DATE object.

Just for fun here is a fiddle that includes a single line chart over time that you can use for reference. http://jsfiddle.net/ghwh8b0m/

Comment: I change the conexion with sql to PDO because i was gettign a depocrate message all  the time, but now i dont see nothings, and when i see the code i get this error  " <b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in etc.. " Also i dunno how to convert the sql database to js date object, but thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are only putting the date plus 2 sets of data into the graph, but you are telling it to expect 3.

```
['Fecha', 'Bateria', 'Mujeres','Sin datos']

['<?php echo date("Y-m-d", $i);?>',<?php echo $totalhombres;?>,<?php echo $totalsindatos;?>, EXTRA DATA NEEDED HERE!]
```

also there is a close bracket beneath this that I don't think needs to be there.

```
 <?php 

 }

 ?>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I remove the bracket and the data "Mujeres" because my graph only needs 1 line, but still doesnt working, thanks for the help